# finding cells in a grid that intersect a given rectangle

Tags: java, math, language-agnostic

(I'll tag this for both Java and language-agnostic, since I think the idea doesn't really require Java, but that's my specific application, so IDK which of the two tags is appropriate).

Let's say I have a grid with an arbitrary number of rows and columns, and and arbitrary cell size.

This grid represents a 2d space.  Now let's say I have a rectangle somewhere in that 2d space - in the past, I remember being able to get back all the cells that intersected the rectangle, (without having to loop), but the math is escaping me at the moment.

To firm up the example, lets say there are 12 rows and 10 columns.  Cells are 256 square (so rows at 256 tall, and columns are 256 wide).  If there was a rectangle at x:400, y:300 that was 200x200, I know that it would intersect the second and third columns in the second row.

So if cell structure was defined like so:

```
// reference[rows][columns]    
SomeCellClass[][] cells = SomeCellClass[12][10]
```

Then the intersections would be `SomeCellClass[1][1]` and `SomeCellClass[1][2]`

And ideally the return would be something like

```
private SomeCellClass[] blah(){
  // do work
  SomeCellClass[] product = new SomeCellClass[total];
  SomeCellClass[0] = // first one that intersects...
  SomeCellClass[1] = // second one that intersects...
  // etc...
}
```

I remember it has something do do with dividing the rectangle position and dimension by cell size and flooring/ceiling to get back the index, but can't get my head around the specifics.  Again, I get how to do this with a loop but would like to be able to use just math and array indices.

Any help would be appreciated.

TYIA.

Comment: If you want to figure out the maths, I suggest just drawing it out on paper...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i tried.  i think i can get the edges, but how to get cells that are in the middle escape me (e.g., imagine a really long rectangle that spanned 4 or 5 columns).

Comment: If you want an array of all the cell indices, then you will need a loop.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i assume you mean a "small" loop related to the rectangle, and not that I have do loop through every cell, right?  The actual application has a very large grid that needs to be examined pretty regularly, so I was hoping to avoid looping over the entire grid each time...

Comment: Oh, yes.  Once you know the edges, then you just loop from xMin to xMax, and from yMin to yMax.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth OK, thanks for you comments.  I'm continuing to try to figure it out on my own but maybe someone will have the solution handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's basically this:

```
int startingColumn = Math.floor( rect.left / columnWidth );
int endingColumn = Math.ceil( rect.right / columnWidth );
int startingRow = Math.floor( rect.top / rowHeight );
int endingRow = Math.ceil( rect.bottom / rowHeight );
```

Then obviously loop from startingColunn/Row through endingColumn/Row.

Comment: You will need to be careful with your upper bounds, depending on whether they are inclusive or exclusive...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks again for you help, but I'm not clear.  If there's any overlap at all, that "qualifies" - is that what you mean?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth er maybe you mean negatives - if the rectangle is above or below the grid?

Comment: I mean: when you say that a rectangle goes from e.g. 100 to 300, is the 300 included, or is 299 the last pixel truly contained within the rectangle?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see, good call.  This is to determine what should be visible on screen at any given time, with respect to a scrolling layout, on a mobile device, so I'm actually going to be adding some "slop" padding as well (so that the cells bordering the viewport are caught as well), so I'll be as generous as possible.